# PHP twitch api check if account exist or not

Tags: php

I'm trying to check if a twitch channel exists or not. Somehow the response I'm receiving if a channel does not exist, or if it got banned, then it shows up as NULL inside the $result variable.

But if i check the api directly, then the response would look like the following:

```
{"error":"Not Found","status":404,"message":"Channel 'd4newhatever2017' does not exist"}
```

How comes my code returns NULL then? Does anyone have a idea?

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Twitch username checker</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="file">Filename:</label> <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Check accounts">
    </form>
    </br>
</body>

</html>

<?php
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
        echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
    elseif ($_FILES["file"]["type"] !== "text/plain")
    {
        echo "File must be a .txt documet.";
    }
    else
    {
        $fp = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'rb');

        while(($line = fgets($fp)) !== false)
        {
            getUserInformations($line);
        }
    }

    function getUserInformations($account)
    {
        $client_id = 'xxx';
        $url = 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/' . $account . '?client_id=' . $client_id;

        $result = file_get_contents($url);
        $result = json_decode($result, true);

        if($result['error'] == 'Not Found')
        {
          echo 'Channel: ' . $account . 'does not exist. </br>';
        }
        else
        {
          echo 'Channel: ' . $account . ' does exist and was created on the following date: ' . date('d-m-Y h:i:s  ',strtotime($result["created_at"])) . '. </br>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely normal. You have to define `ignore_errors` [flag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php) to `True` if you want to fetch results for different statuses than 200.

Replace `$result = file_get_contents($url);` with

```
$result = file_get_contents(
    $url,
    false,
    stream_context_create(
        array(
            'http' => array(
                 'ignore_errors' => true
            )
        )
    )
);
```